# How to get Labels to appear on markers in ArcGis Maps webpart for SharePoint?

Tags: arcgis

I'm using the Arcgis Maps web part for SharePoint.  I can get my markers / pins to appear, now I'm trying to get labels to appear identifying each.  How do I go about this?

Please see screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find work around by simply building the map using Arcgis's Online tool (Arcgis Online) I'm not sure if the webpart is buggy, but the Online version is simple and intuitive.  I pulled the map into a Web Page Viewer web part.  It works very well.